Conda environment activation on compute node
I'm running Quantum Espresso with a conda environment and want to use a host file to run my calculations on the compute node.
On the head node I activate the concerned environment using conda activate espresso and then do an mpirun.
The calculation returns a tree spawn error:

orted: Error: unknown option "--tree-spawn" ORTE does not know how to
route a message to the specified daemon located on the indicated node:
my node:   hpc   target node:  compute-0-1

I figured that it was because the correct conda environment wasn't being activated on the compute node.
I managed to bypass it by adding conda activate espresso to the bashrc file.
Is there a more elegant solution?
